# Why is the time complexity of Dijkstra O((V + E) logV)

Tags: complexity-theory, dijkstra

I was reading about worst case time complexity for the Dijkstra algorithm using binary heap (the graph being represented as adjacency list).

According to wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Running_time) and various stackoverflow questions, this is `O((V + E) logV)` where E - number of edges, V - number of vertices. However I found no explanation as to why it can't be done in `O(V + E logV)`.

> With a self-balancing binary search tree or binary heap, the algorithm requires `Θ((E+V) logV)` time in the worst case

In case E >= V, the complexity reduces to `O(E logV)` anyway. Otherwise, we have `O(E)` vertices in the same connected component as the start vertex (and the algorithm ends once we get to them). On each iteration we obtain one of these vertices, taking `O(logV)` time to remove it from the heap.
Each update of the distance to a connected vertex takes `O(logV)` and the number of these updates is bound by the number of edges E so in total we do `O(E)` such updates. Adding `O(V)` time for initializing distances, we get final complexity `O(V + E logV)`.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Wikipedia reports the complexity as Θ(E + V log V), but does also say that the original algorithm using a min-priority queue has complexity Θ(V + E log V). Please link to the sources which say otherwise.

Comment: @kaya3 I see which section you're referring to. I added a link to what I read. A SO comment by DBedrenko in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26548129/515212 claims the same. The same complexity also appears here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-complexity-of-Dijkstras-algorithm